# Rails: Rake Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and I'm working at a project at the moment.

I actually did not really implement tests during my work. So now after a few days I wanted to write tests for my recent work. But rake prints out a lot of errors which I don't understand. Maybe someone knows what's the problem here?

Test:

```
test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
end
```

Error Output:

```
MoviesControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
   (in /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in`_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__864529937_93991640'
   test/controllers/movies_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:MoviesControllerTest>'
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You are trying to get some path called home. The get method acts like some trys to visit the page. May you normally call it with additional parameters which are missing in the test case.

Comment: This is a controller test which should only check if the home site gets returned. I did this according to the rails testing guide. But maybe I just don't understand your point